# idiom for compiling library with makefile

Tags: c, makefile

```
LIB = lib.a

LIBMEMB = $(LIB)(a.o) $(LIB)(b.o) $(LIB)(c.o)

$(LIB) : $(LIBMEMB)

.c.a:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $*.o
    rm -f $*.o
```

Since `.c.a` part is same with inference rule, I thought above makefile is some kind of widely-used idiom for making libraries.
However, I'm thinking this kind of situation:

- you have compiled it already, using above makefile, so `lib.a` file is present.
- then you want to change your code structure, or you don't like your file name, or whatever, so you changed your source files to `b.c` `d.c` `f.c` from `a.c` `b.c` `c.c`.

So you change your makefile like this:

```
LIB = lib.a

LIBMEMB = $(LIB)(b.o) $(LIB)(d.o) $(LIB)(f.o)

$(LIB) : $(LIBMEMB)

.c.a:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $*.o
    rm -f $*.o
```

Then `a.o` and `c.o` would still be in `lib.a`, but it shouldn't. Since this is a common situation, I think there must be some widely-used idiom to remove library members which doesn't specified in makefile, but I couldn't find anything. Obviously, you can make `clean` rule, like

```
clean :
    rm -f $(LIB)
```

and call it whenever you changed your file name, or remove some files, etc, but since our purpose of writing makefile is to compile only what is changed, I think that solution is not good. What is a good way to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: There is no way to handle this using this model, except by running `clean`.  You can either not use this method at all and rebuild the static library from scratch every time rather than just replacing the changed objects, or run `clean` if you delete objects.  There's no facility for removing objects that exist in the library but aren't mentioned in the makefile.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway that is really disappointing.

Comment: It seems much cleaner to explicitly list your dependencies.  And use a separate rule to generate .o files.  (Indeed, just rely on the builtin rule.)

Comment: Actually if you use make's built-in archive handling I believe it will already do basically exactly the same thing as this: it will build the `.o`, then replace it in the archive, and then since these `.o`'s are considered intermediates file make will delete them.  However, that won't help with the question being asked.  You'll still have the same problem.

Comment: How would you expect Make to help you? You might consult the archiver's documentation how to remove non-listed modules. (Even if I think there is not such option.) Anyway, building a library with ar is really quick compared to compiling, basically it is just concatenating the object files.